Подключение для отладки своей библиотеки npm
У меня есть организация/библиотека на npm (выглядит так @my-org/core, @my-org/func, @my-org/models). В библиотеках хранятся общие типы и логики по работе, и они будут юзаться для пока что 3х проектов. Я хочу отладить их (без пуша и так далее в npm). Почитал - чтобы ссылаться на либу надо в билде сделать глобальную символическую ссылку и потом в своем проекте сослаться на нее. Делайю в билде npm link - ссылка создается, все гуд. После в своем проекте делай подвязку npm link @my-org/core - все гуд (в папке node_modules создается папка @my-org и в ней ссылка core. Но как только я хочу подвязать еще одну линку (@my-org/func) - то в папке @my-org удаляется ссылка на core и появляется func. Как сделать так чтобы сохранить все ссылки (их больше 2х, но как хотя бы 2 сделать) ???

Пробовал сделать так: npm link @my-org/core @my-org/func ?
